# Additional axis when replotting 3D figure using canvas.draw()

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

I have what is probably a very simple problem replotting some 3D data using Matplotlib. Initially, I have an figure with a 3D projection on a canvas:

```
self.fig = plt.figure()
self.canvas = FigCanvas(self.mainPanel, -1, self.fig)
self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
```

[image]

I then add some data and use canvas.draw() to update. The plot itself updates as expected, but I get additional 2D axis on the outside of the figure (-0.05 to 0.05) and I can't work out how to stop it:

```
self.axes.clear()
self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

xs = np.random.random_sample(100)
ys = np.random.random_sample(100)
zs = np.random.random_sample(100)

self.axes.scatter(xs, ys, zs, c='r', marker='o')
self.canvas.draw()
```

[image]

Any ideas? I'm going in circles right now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joquin's suggestions worked well and highlighted that I was probably going about plotting the wrong way to start with. However, for the sake of completeness, I eventually found that you can get rid of the 2D axis simply by using:

```
self.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
self.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
```

This seems to be one way at least of removing the 2D labels from 3D plots if they appear.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `axes.clear()` + `fig.add_subplot`, use the `remove` method of the `mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Patch3DCollection` object:

```
In [31]: fig = plt.figure()

In [32]: ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

In [33]: xs = np.random.random_sample(100)

In [34]: ys = np.random.random_sample(100)

In [35]: zs = np.random.random_sample(100)

In [36]: a = ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs, c='r', marker='o')   #draws

In [37]: a.remove()                                      #clean

In [38]: a = ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs, c='r', marker='o')   #draws again
```

If you still have problems you can play with this:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import interactive
interactive(True)

xs = np.random.random_sample(100)
ys = np.random.random_sample(100)
zs = np.random.random_sample(100)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

a = ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs, c='r', marker='o')

plt.draw()

raw_input('press for new image')

a.remove()

xs = np.random.random_sample(1000)
ys = np.random.random_sample(1000)
zs = np.random.random_sample(1000)

a = ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs, c='r', marker='o')

plt.draw()

raw_input('press to end')
```

Comment: Hi Joaquin,
Thanks for taking the time to reply. I tried this but it doesn't seem to work. remove() seems to clear the 3D scatter data but does nothing to the axis. Furthermore, the 2D axis (-0.05 to 0.05 on the outside of the figure) is still there. Any other ideas?

Comment: The label of the 2D axis should not be there in the first place. Did you remove the axes.clear() line from you code ?

Comment: Hi there,
Yes I did. The first time it draws, the 2D axis aren't present. But the second time, they appear again. Code is:
xs = np.random.random_sample(100)*40 - 20
ys = np.random.random_sample(100)*40 - 20
zs = np.random.random_sample(100)*40 - 20
a = self.axes.scatter(xs, ys, zs, c='r', marker='o')
a.remove()
a = self.axes.scatter(xs, ys, zs, c='r', marker='o')
self.canvas.draw()

Comment: @Dan Pearce  I edited and added some few lines just to prevent misunderstandings. Maybe the problem now is in your canvas.draw(). I dont use any canvas to draw.

Comment: If I use just the remove() function, the 2D axis don't appear but the data from the previous plot isn't cleared. If I use ax.cla(), ax.clf(), ax.hold(True), ax.hold(False) or ax.clear() anywhere in there, the 2D axis appear. Clearly I'm missing something here...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4606/discussion-between-dan-and-joaquin)